# React + Redux function call

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I am quite new to React + Redux and am having some issues with pretty basic stuff.

In my dropdown component I was planning to trigger two function calls but it doesn't seem to pass my data as I expected it to.

The following works properly:

```
onChange={this.props.handleDropdownChange}
```

When I console.log the action in my reducer it has the correct type, key and payload.

The following does NOT work:

```
onChange={(event) => { this.props.handleDropdownChange(event)}}
```

I end up with the correct type but the rest is now undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update #1 on request**
This is the definition of handleDropdownChange:

```
export const handleDropdownChange = actionCreator(DROPDOWN_HANDLER, 'event', 'key', 'payload')
```

actionCreator is a very basic function that simply creates an action object based on the type (a defined constant) and a dynamic list of arguments. Like I said before, it works as expected in the first example. The only thing I do then is console.log the action in my reducer.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `handleDropdownChange` definition?

Comment: Sure, it's not much but perhaps it helps.

Comment: You can do something like `onChange={(...args) => { this.props.handleDropdownChange(...args)}}` but onChange only passes the *event*, you can also do something like `onChange={(event) => { this.props.handleDropdownChange(event, key, payload)}}`

Comment: this seems to be working  onClick = { (event) = > { this.props.methodOne(event, payloadOne) ; this.props.methodTwo(  event , payloadTwo) } ... Where exactly is the issue? Any fiddle if possible ?

Comment: Sorry about the very late reply, had to deal with other projects before getting back to this one. I actually don't know what went wrong, now everything seems to work just fine, making two function calls as well. Thanks all for the help!