# React-Redux: Passing arguments from handler to action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have scoured the web and various sources; none seem to apply to my question. The closest might be this (which doesn't have an answer): 
[React + Redux function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962016/react-redux-function-call)

So: I am attempting to pass arguments along to one of my action creator fields, a function called update which will determine if the blurred row had a value changed, and if so it will call my api to update. The arguments I wish to pass are the event (which contains the row I need as target.ParentElement) and an integer that represents the index of the row in my state's **projects** property.

Action creator in my redux store:

```
export const actionCreators = {
    update: (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement> | undefined, i: number): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
        let test = event;
        // Will put logic and api call in here and dispatch the proper action type
    }
}
```

And trying to call it like so:

```
// Inside a function rendering each row in my form 
...
<input key={project.number} name={name} className='trackerCell' onBlur={(event) => { this.props.update(event, i) }} defaultValue={project.number}/>
```

Where **i** is the index value, passed to the rendering function.

This all compiles find, however when I execute and get into the **update** function, **e** and **i** are both undefined; **event** is defined though, and looks as I would expect **e** to look.

FWIW, the format I'm attempting here works elsewhere in my application:

```
requestProjects: (programNumber: number, programString: string): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
```

when called by componentWillUpdate() properly receives a number and string that I am able to use in my logic.

Bonus: In all my action creator functions constructed this way, **arguments** has 3 objects in it: **dispatch**, **getState** and **undefined**. Why don't the arguments in the call signature show up? Am I thinking about these arguments differently?

And yes, I know I can just attach the index value to an attribute in my input and that will appear in the **event** object, but this seems hacky, and I want to actually understand what is going on here.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

In response to Will Cain's comment: The index variable, i, is passed to the row rendering function from it's parent, as such:

```
private renderProjectRow(project: ProjectTrackerState.Project, i: number) {
    let cells: JSX.Element[] = [];
    let someKey = project.number + '_started', name = project.number + '_number';
    cells.push(<input key={project.number} name={name} className='trackerCell' onBlur={ this._handleBlur.bind(this) } defaultValue={project.number}/>);
// Rendering continues down here
```

It's a valid number type up to the event point (I can tell as I debug in the browser).

The event variable in the update function comes from.. I don't know where? That's a mystery I would love to solve. Even though it is not a defined parameter to the update function, when I enter the **update** method, event is defined as such in the debugger:

```
Event {isTrusted: false, type: "react-blur", target: react, currentTarget: react, eventPhase: 2, …}
```

It is clearly the event that triggered the handler, but how it reaches the **update** function is beyond me.

Comment: Can you share where `i` comes from in the call `this.props.update(event, i)` and where `event` comes from in the `update` function?

Comment: Sure, I amended the original post with some updated info

Answer (score 1):

Answering this in case anyone comes across this same issue (unlikely, but want to be helpful):

The reason my arguments *e* and *i* were undefined at runtime is because they were not referenced in the function execution. My guess (still looking for documentation to verify) is that typescript cleans up references to unused parameters. Makes sense from an optimization standpoint. Adding a read reference to *e* and *i* inside the **update** function solved my issue.

You can add `"noUnusedParameters": true` to your `compilerOptions` in your *tsconfig* file and this will throw a typescript error for all these parameters so you can catch when these cleanups would be done.